# Don't see nodeJs serveur port working / same port client/server don't cause error

Tags: node.js, server, port, vps

I have an application which work with React/socket/nodeJS on a VPS.

This VPS use apache as php engine and when I check the config, it listens the port `7080`.

My nodeJS work on any port `80` / `3000` / `7080` etc... and when I use `netstat` on my console VPS I don't see this `<IP:SERVERPORT>`.

Here is the problem I face:

**1.** Why I can't see my server PORT running on my VPS with netstats? ( I see console log from my server so he work)

**2.** Why it work with the same apache port? Normally I have to use a server port different from the client...

For information, my vps is dedibox (online.net with plesk).

Comment: use `netstat -a`

Comment: yeah I already do it but it didn't appear

Comment: And even if it appear I don't understand why it work , listen on the same port client/server

Comment: ^ as in? Explain more.

Comment: My client side is working with apache on port 7080, it's a reactjs application
My server side is working with  nodejs on port 80 or 7080 or anyport. 

My question is : Normally if server and client have the same port it will show an error?